# Double free error with a destructor of a Linked List-like class

Tags: c++, class, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

For a project at school, in order to learn c++, I have to work on different classes.
One of them is the class `Number`, which is a representation of numbers as a Linked list :

```
class Number {
public:
    Number( unsigned long l ) {
        first_ = new Digit{ static_cast< DigitType >( l % number_base ), nullptr };
        if ( l >= number_base ) {
            first_->next_ = (Number( l / number_base )).first_;
        }
    }
    ~Number() {        
        [...]
    }

private:
    using DigitType = unsigned int;
    static const DigitType number_base{ 10u };
    struct Digit {
        DigitType digit_;
        Digit * next_;
    };
    Digit * first_;
};
```

`Number n{ 123 };` will therefore be n -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> `nullptr`

I have to code the destructor, so I went with an approach similar to Single Linked List :

```
~Number() {        
        Digit * current_address = first_;
        while (current_address != nullptr) {
            Digit * next_address = current_address->next_;
            delete current_address;
            current_address = next_address;
        }
    }
```

I then run this simple snippet to see if it works :

```
//Another file
#include <exception>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include "Number.hpp"

void print_number() {
    Number n{ 10 };
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    print_number();
    std::cout << "Finished !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}



./a.out
Starting...
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I think I might have some misunderstanding about dynamic allocation, because I feel like my destructor doesn't try to free twice the same address... Any idea of what is happening ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `first_->next_ = (Number( l / number_base )).first_;` is very problematic, you are assigning a pointer from your temporary object (whose destructor will be called right after this line is executed)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
first_->next_ = (Number( l / number_base )).first_;
```

This creates a temporaries number which, after it is created, will call its destructor, deallocating memory.

A better way to do this is to simply use a loop instead of recursion.

However, if you are stuck to recursion, then instead of recursively calling the constructor, call a helper function which has the exact same logic.

I will leave it up to you to implement these ideas.